# while signing the pdf it returns Error UNABLE_TO_LOAD_DOCUMENT

Tags: docusignapi

while loading pdf in docusign API in order to sign the pdf file, it gives error "Unable to load the document.". I am attaching the pdf for reference.

full error message is as below from API:

```
<errorDetails xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<errorCode>UNABLE_TO_LOAD_DOCUMENT</errorCode>
<message>Unable to load the document. Unable to load Document(1;
Retail AMP - Pexe CO-1 MM Piza Hut-RDE-CC21.pdf). Error: Expected Base.String</message>
</errorDetails>
```

Please find below Docusign link for reference:
https://support.docusign.com/en/cases/05599635

Thanks.

Comment: We would need to see the code you wrote to load this document. The document is just fine. The error seems to suggest that you didn't encode it correctly when uploading it using the API. Did you use Base64 encoding?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to send documents to DocuSign via the API:

1. You can use Base64 encoding, which means you serialize the document into a very long string. If you used this method - please ensure that you correctly sereaized the document and that the string you send in the API call, is inedeed a correct string representing a base64 PDF.
2. You can send it as a binary transfer, this more efficient and less popular mean of uploading documents via the API. You can find out how to do this and see an example of code to upload files:

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-send-binary